# Paperclip | ImageMagick - Unable to resize image with custom height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using Paperclip's custom styles to resize some images.

The custom style is defined as so -

```
  has_attached_file :image_preview,
                                    :styles => lambda { |a|
                    { 
                      :original => "#{a.instance.model.aspect_ratio_width.to_f/2.54*300}x#{a.instance.model.aspect_ratio_height.to_f/2.54*300}"}
                  }
```

When the output is seen, the image was resized the the width parameter but never the height parameter!

In the logs as well, I see that only the width parameter was taking into consideration during the ImageMagick operation --

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/46711c9258f556a83aa382084f5014d120160804-14501-h9qo6j.png'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/46711c9258f556a83aa382084f5014d120160804-14501-16cbj3b.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/46711c9258f556a83aa382084f5014d120160804-14501-16cbj3b.png[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/46711c9258f556a83aa382084f5014d120160804-14501-16cbj3b.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "1110" '/tmp/caba5ed9a9c1d9623acb7738fd6b8dda20160804-14501-5sjqq1'
[paperclip] saving /cases/image_previews/000/000/045/original/Goku-Blue.png
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a height and a  width like that:

`has_attached_file :image_preview, :styles { original: "1920x1080>", thumb: "300x300#" }`

The '#' will cut the image in the center to the given dimensions.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start

Comment: the width the height are dynamically given.